# how to select 3 columns in SQL and do a COUNT make an INNER JOIN and display them as the 3 columns but with no duplicate information

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to list the names and codes of vendors and the number of products each vendor has supplied, i.e. vendor XXX has supplied xxx products, and vendor YYY has supplied yyy products etc. I have already tried these queries but am not receiving the result I want.

```
SELECT p_code, 
       product.v_code, 
       vendor.v_name 
FROM   product 
    CROSS JOIN vendor; 

SELECT p_code, 
       vendor.v_code, 
       v_name 
FROM   product 
       JOIN vendor 
         ON vendor.v_code = product.v_code; 

SELECT v_code, 
       Count(DISTINCT( p_code )) 
FROM   product 
GROUP  BY v_code 
UNION 
SELECT v_name, 
       v_code AS NAME 
FROM   vendor; 

SELECT product.p_code, 
   product.v_code, 
   vendor.v_name 
FROM   product 
   INNER JOIN vendor 
           ON product.v_code = vendor.v_code;
```

This is what the tables and columns are;

Similar output but needs vendor name listed as well:

[image: SIMILAR OUTPUT BUT NEEDS VENDOR NAME LISTED AS WELL]

Sample tables

[image: SAMPLE Tables]

Comment: share your sample data and expected output

Comment: The DataBase Tables link is the sample and my expected output is what I am having the issue with. I need to have 3 columns V_CODE, P_CODE( but shown as a number of products sold by individual vendor) and V_NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below using inner join and aggregation:

```
SELECT VENDOR.V_CODE, V_NAME,count(distinct P_CODE) as productcount
FROM PRODUCT JOIN VENDOR ON VENDOR.V_CODE = PRODUCT.V_CODE
group by VENDOR.V_CODE, V_NAME
```

Comment: Ah man that is it perfect thanks so much you are a champion :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try these query too gives same result as "f@06" query.

```
select vendor.v_name, product.v_code, count(p_code) from product join vendor on product.v_code = vendor.v_code group by product.v_code;
```